# Что значит ошибка cannot resolve method?

Tags: api, java

Всем привет.

Думаю, в заголовке все понятно. В коде в нескольких местах пишет данную ошибку, хотя нужные методы есть, использую Forge API.

Answer (score 5):

Ошибка значит ровно то, о чем сообщает: компилятор не может найти метод с аргументами нужного типа.